# Optimizing code that loops through pixels

Tags: c, image-processing, optimization

I got a 200x200 image, as a byte array of pixels (3 bytes for each pixel, representing RGB values). I'd like to select all border points, defined as a point that is not white, and lies either on the border of the image or has a neighbouring pixel of a different color.

Wrote simple C code for this :

```
int i = 0, row = 0, column = 0, width3 = width*3;
char r,g,b;
while (i < length) {

    r = pixels[i], g = pixels[i+1], b = pixels[i+2];

    if (r != -1 || g != -1 || b != -1) { // Not white
        // Check for border point
        if (column == 0 || column == width-1 || row == 0 || row == height-1
            || r != pixels[i-3] || r != pixels[i+3] || r != pixels[i-width3] || r != pixels[i+width3]
            || g != pixels[i-2] || g != pixels[i+4] || g != pixels[i-width3+1] || g != pixels[i+width3+1]
            || b != pixels[i-1] || b != pixels[i+5] || b != pixels[i-width3+2] || b != pixels[i+width3+2]) {
            // Border point
        }
    }

    i += 3;

    if (++column == width) {
        column = 0;
        row++;
        // printf("new row");
    }

}
```

Now I'd like to know how I can speed this up as much as possible.
Either I could use the GPU but the transfer of memory from and to the GPU is quite costly.

Since I'm totally new to any kind of optimisation techniques such as those used in openCV, I'd like to know if there's any way to make my snippet faster.

(for more context ; I want to interpret border points of each non-white object on the image as 'contours' of a visible object and then use Douglas-Peucker to approximate the contours as a polygon)

Comment: Take care that `pixels[i-3]` and `pixels[i+5]` don't break the array bounds. You don't show how `i` starts but you do show `i < length`.

Comment: They can't since I first check for border points. `i`, `row` and `column` start at 0 and goes through all bytes (3 bytes at a time, for RGB values). `width3` is `width*3`, which is 600 in the case of 200x200 images (should add all of this to the snippet I guess).

Comment: "I could use the GPU but the transfer of memory from and to the GPU is quite costly."  Surely not as costly as doing the entire operation in the CPU!  IIRC copying to VRAM is only slightly slower than a regular `memcpy`.

Comment: Are you sure? The problem with GPU is that I want to add border points to separate queues per color, but I'm not sure how to do that with the GPU (very new to all of this).

Comment: @0x5453 Is this well suited for the GPU to output a list of border points? The output has to be serial in nature, I assume, like a variable-sized list of x/y pairs, or else the CPU might have to do something expensive just to read back whatever the GPU outputs. I'm a total novice to GPGPU but it seems awkward given the serial nature of the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few micro-optimizations:

- reorganize the loop on the rows to only access pairs of pixels wholly inside the image, so that you needn't test the column and row indexes;
- do not test left and right: if two pixels differ, a single comparison suffices for both;
- test only for white in case you detect a border point (they are only a fraction of the image area);

Your 12 comparisons test (to be reduced to 6) might be efficient, as it uses shortcut logics (so that all tests are performed only in uniform areas). You may try and trade it for a branchless expression, which will always be executed in full, but avoids costly conditional branches: use `r0 - r1 | g0 - g1 | b0 - b1`, which is only zero for identical colors.

Or even better, load whole pixels at a time as an integer value, computing the appropriate offset, xor them and mask out the extra byte: `(*(unsigned int*)pixels ^ *(unsigned int*)(pixels + 3)) >> 8`.

If this is not enough , you can consider to use the vector instruction set (SSE/AVX), but this is yet another story.

Comment: I test for white because it's usually a rather large fraction of the image area, but it would have made sense otherwise. 

I don't understand the first item ; I test for column and row indexes because each non-white pixel on the image border is a border point. Do you think I should separate the checks for the image border? 

Would definitely like to know more about SSE/AVX btw, I skimmed through the wiki but wouldn't know how to use it in my case.

Comment: @HaraKikiri: loop on column=0 to column=width-2 inclusive, inside a loop on row. Consider my suggestion about integers, it handles the three components at a time. SSE is a too large topic to address here.

Comment: The integer loading seems to help a great deal. Thanks a lot. If you have any links to share about SSE, I'd be glad to do some reading.

Comment: Why does it now consider the last pixel non-white, as well as any left-most border point? For some reason it seems to be shifted 16 times to the right.

Comment: @HaraKikiri: what is the speedup that you get ?

Comment: Used to get about 0.55ms, now about 0.35. Superb for me tbh, as there aren't that many border points left to process (maybe 400), so my whole thing takes under a ms compared with using java code which regularly takes more than a ms for just detecting border points. Plus I'm probably gonna use a hash table and with your proposal I already have the rgb in an int, which can be used as the hash code.

Comment: @HaraKikiri: I exected a better improvement :(

Comment: Well I'm happy with it, only thing is that if there is a non-white pixel to the right of the current pixel, the rgb of the current pixel becomes weird. If the current pixel is white it's like it shifts to the right twice. Any idea why? Seems like a silly error.

Comment: Well I managed to make it work (had to be (pixels -1) instead of (pixels), (pixels + 2) instead of (pixels + 3), ... always subtracting 1). [See here for comparison of speed JAVA versus JNI implementation](https://imgur.com/a/VgRYf)

Comment: @HaraKikiri: this is what I meant by "computing the appropriate offset" ;-)

Comment: @HaraKikiri: mh, the comparison of Java vs. JNI is not so instructive. I am more interested in the comparison of JNI "old" code vs. JNI "new" code.

Comment: The difference is not that large then, but it can't really be, since the loop without any comparison logic is at least 0,12ms.

Comment: "I already have the rgb in an int [...]" Did you actually make your image 32-bit (4 bytes per pixel)? That could slow things down a tad over 24-bit but it does make SIMD easier if so.